# cookie issue in IE only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies, cross-browser

i have this code for creating cookie

This works in firefox and crome browser but in IE it is creating cookie again and again

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["cook"])) {
    $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 2;
    $data = array(
        "ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        "browser" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        "create_time" => $now
    );
    $result = $db->insert("cookies", $data);
    $cookie_id = $db->lastid;
    $cookie_id = my_encrypt($cookie_id);
    setcookie("cook", $cookie_id, $expire,"/","localhost");
} else {
    $cookie_id = $_COOKIE["cook"];
}
```

Everytime I visit page it creates new cookie

Comment: Just tried your code and couldn't reproduce the problem! I'm using IE9

Comment: Can Anyone help to solve to this problem >\?

Answer (score 0):

omit the `domain`-parameter for `setcookie()`

Comment: Yes I removed domain parameter but now I am not able to logout

Comment: When "logout" means: **deleting the cookie**, also ommit the domain when deleting the cookie.

Comment: Actually I am using cookie for some other data and session for logging and logout...

Comment: A session usually uses cookies too, I guess the value of `session.cookie_domain` is **localhost** . Use `ini_set()` and set this value to an empty string when the script runs at the localhost.